# Spatial weight for PySAL from a geojson file or geodataframe?

Tags: python, pysal, moran-index

I want to calculate the Moran I value of a geojson file through python. Recently I am trying to use [pysal](http://pysal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and I find that I need to get the a spatial weight to realize it. But from the [official guide](http://pysal.readthedocs.io/en/v1.11.0/library/weights/user.html) it seems that it only supports shapefiles. I am wondering whether I can get spatial weight from a geojson file without convert it to shapefile or if there are any others tools for calculating spatial autocorrelation with geojson file or geodataframe in python.

Comment: What are the geometries you are working with ? Polygons, points, etc ... ?

Comment: Currently it's polygon but I can convert it to the centroid by geopandas.

Comment: I think keeping you geometries as Polygons is better, since you may want to build contiguity matrices. Also I think you should consider turning your geojsons into shapefiles so as to benefit from the whole potential that pysal offers. Is writing shapefiles really a "don't" in your case ?

Comment: I prefer not to use shapefile in the current stage. But if there are no other choices I will try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let us ***try*** to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```
geoj = {
  'type': 'FeatureCollection',
  'features':
  {
    'type': 'Feature',
    'geometry': {
      'type': 'Polygon',
      'coordinates': [
          [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0],
            [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ],
          [ [101.0, 0.0], [102.0, 0.0], [102.0, 1.0],
            [101.0, 1.0], [101.0, 0.0] ],
          [ [100.0, 1.0], [101.0, 1.0], [101.0, 2.0],
            [100.0, 2.0], [100.0, 1.0] ],
          [ [101.0, 1.0], [102.0, 1.0], [102.0, 2.0],
            [101.0, 2.0], [101.0, 1.0] ],
          ]
      }
    }
  }
```

One needs to make `geoj` be a pysal supported type, as follows

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pysal as ps
>>> import shapely.geometry as shg

>>> coords= geoj["features"]["geometry"]["coordinates"]
>>> polys = [
       ps.cg.asShape(shg.Polygon(c))
       for c in coords
    ]
>>> points = [
        p.centroid
        for p in polys
    ]
>>> points_as_array = np.array(points) # I am not sure if this is mandatory in recent versions of pysal
```

---

To model binary correlation structure, you can use the function [`knnW_from_array`](http://pysal.readthedocs.io/en/v1.11.0/library/weights/user.html#pysal.weights.user.knnW_from_array)

```
>>> wnn2 = ps.knnW_from_array(points_as_array, 2) # deprecated and removed soon (or later), and replaced by KNN.from_array
>>> wnn2.transform = 'r' # make wnn2 be row-stochastic
>>> wnn2.neighbors
{0: [2, 1], 1: [3, 0], 2: [3, 0], 3: [1, 2]}
>>> wnn2.weights
{0: [0.5, 0.5], 1: [0.5, 0.5], 2: [0.5, 0.5], 3: [0.5, 0.5]}

>>> wnn3 = ps.knnW_from_array(points_as_array, 3)
>>> wnn3.transform = 'r'
>>> wnn3.neighbors
{0: [2, 1, 3], 1: [0, 3, 2], 2: [0, 3, 1], 3: [2, 1, 0]}
>>> wnn3.full()[0]
array([[ 0.        ,  0.33333333,  0.33333333,  0.33333333],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.        ,  0.33333333,  0.33333333],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.33333333,  0.        ,  0.33333333],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.33333333,  0.33333333,  0.        ]])
```

---

Thanks to [Sir Anselin and his modeling team](http://pysal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/introduction.html), let us do what we want, modeling, say, continuous interactions of the type distance decay whose parameter is based on the well known gravity model: `alpha=2`.

One first has to turn `points_as_array` into an object of the type [`scipy.spatial.ckdtree.cKDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html)

```
>>> kd = ps.common.KDTree(points_as_array)
```

retrieve distances as sparse matrix

```
>>> dmat = kd.sparse_distance_matrix(kd, max_distance=1e50)
```

As you can see, I choose such a big threshold that the matrix is very unlikely to be sparse actually. Now one initiates our `neighbors` and `weights` variables, mandatory to instantiate a [`pysal.weights.weights.W`](http://pysal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/weights/weights.html) object, as follows

```
>>> ids       = np.arange(dmat.shape[0]) # If one has no ids to provide
>>> neighbors = dict([(i,[]) for i in ids])
>>> weights   = dict([(i,[]) for i in ids])
```

which can now be filled with neighborhoods and distance-decreasing weights

```
>>> for key,distance in dmat.items():           
    i,j = key
    if j not in neighbors[i]:
        weights[i].append(pow(distance,-alpha))
        neighbors[i].append(j)
    if i not in neighbors[j]:
        weights[j].append(pow(distance,-alpha))
        neighbors[j].append(i)
>>> wd2 = ps.weights.W(neighbors, weights)
>>> wd2.transform = 'r'
>>> wd2.full()[0]
array([[ 0. ,  0.4,  0.4,  0.2],
       [ 0.4,  0. ,  0.2,  0.4],
       [ 0.4,  0.2,  0. ,  0.4],
       [ 0.2,  0.4,  0.4,  0. ]])
```

---

***Let us play with [Moran's I](http://pysal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/tutorials/autocorrelation.html#moran-s-i)***

```
>>> y = np.array([21., 79., 49., 51.])
>>> mi_wnn2 = ps.Moran(y, wnn2, two_tailed=False)
>>> mi_wnn3 = ps.Moran(y, wnn3, two_tailed=False)
>>> mi_wd2  = ps.Moran(y, wd2, two_tailed=False)
>>> mi_wnn2.I, mi_wnn2.p_norm
(-0.46555819477434679, 0.32870362604749792)
>>> mi_wnn3.I, mi_wnn3.p_norm
(-0.33333333333333337, 0.49999999579646004)
>>> mi_wd2.I, mi_wd2.p_norm
(-0.38622327790973882, 0.3287036260474977)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer! By the way, what should I do in this case if I want to calculate Moran I based on some attribute? (such as [this tutorial](http://darribas.org/gds15/content/labs/lab_06.html))

Comment: You are welcome. I am happy to help. What do you mean exactly by *attribute* ? Is the variable `y` above not what you are talking about ?

Comment: Oh sorry for my carelessness. That is what I need. Thanks again for your help.